# Can we use SiriKit for anything else than the 6 types of services it is supposed to support?

Tags: ios, sirikit

I'm quite interested in `SiriKit` but my app doesn't implement any of the 6 services that `SiriKit` supports :

- Audio or video calling
- Messaging
- Payments
- Searching photos
- Workouts
- Ride booking

I actually don't understand why `SiriKit` only supports these services.

In my case, I have a huge database and I would like a user to be able to use Siri to search in this database. The user could say something like "Siri, search Bob Lenon in *my app name*".

I guess it's not possible, otherwise it would be written in the Apple documentation, but I'm just wondering why it is not possible.

Comment: No. It's not possible. To understand why, you could ask in the Apple Developer Forums. If you have luck, an Apple employee answers your question. On SO, we can just guess possible reasons ;-)

Comment: Yeah, I was thinking that maybe someone would have an answer here, I didn't have so much success on Apple Developer Forum so far :)